# Merge two JavaScript Objects and conflicting properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, merge, javascript-objects

Say I have two objects:

```js
var obj1 = {cars: 'ford', fruit: 'peach', other: ['bar']}
var obj2 = {cars: 'ferrari', info: 'foo', other: ['baz']}
```

Now I want to merge these two objects and any conflicting properties. Expected result:

```js
{cars: ['ford', 'ferrari'], fruit: 'peach', info: 'foo', other: ['bar', 'baz']}
```

However, using object spread

```js
{...obj1, ...obj2}
```

Returns

```js
{cars: 'ferrari', fruit: 'peach', info: 'foo', other: ['baz']}
```

Is there a way to merge the two objects and merge conflicting properties into arrays instead of overriding?
**Note: I need pure JS**

Comment: You'll have to manually loop through the items of the object and create the new object

Comment: @rzwnahmd can you provide a function to do that?

Comment: There is an answer that shows a pure JavaScript way of doing this. The Lodash library does make the code more concise.

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry, but I need to do this using pure javascript...

Comment: the datastructure you're describing is a multi-map, in case you want to search more around the topic.

Comment: @Jake then you're in luck because *as I said* there are pure JavaScript answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge by property and check if target is not an array or if thje value is an array.

```js
const
    merge = (target, source) => Object.entries(source).reduce((o, [k, v]) => {
        if (k in o) {
            if (!Array.isArray(o[k])) o[k] = [o[k]];
            [].concat(v).forEach(item => {
                if (!o[k].includes(item)) o[k].push(item);
            });
        } else {
            o[k] = v;
        }
        return o;
    }, target);

var obj1 = { cars: 'ford', fruit: 'peach', other: ['bar'] },
    obj2 =  {cars: 'ferrari', info: 'foo', other: ['baz'] },
    result = [obj1, obj2].reduce(merge, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to code it manually, there is no automatic way to do that type of merge.  And, because of the way you want to merge arrays, it take a number of special conditions:

```js
var obj1 = {cars: 'ford', fruit: 'peach', other: ['bar']}
var obj2 = {cars: 'ferrari', info: 'foo', other: ['baz']}

function merge(obj1, obj2) {
    let result = Object.assign({}, obj1);
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
        if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (!Array.isArray(result[key])) {
                // target isn't an array yet, have to convert it to an array
                result[key] = [result[key]];
            }
            // now copy over either a single entry or an array of entries
            if (Array.isArray(obj2[key])) {
                // copy all the array entries over to the other array
                result[key].push(...obj2[key]);
            } else {
                // copy single entry over to the other array
                result[key].push(obj2[key]);
            }
        } else {
            // result doesn't have this property yet, just copy the value over
            result[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(merge(obj1, obj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should works too:

```
function mergeObject(o1, o2) {
  return {
    ...o2,
    ...Object.keys(o1).reduce((r, c) => ({
      ...r, [c]: o2.hasOwnProperty(c) ? [
        ...(Array.isArray(o1[c]) ? o1[c] : [o1[c]]),
        ...(Array.isArray(o2[c]) ? o2[c] : [o2[c]]),
      ] : o1[c]
    }), {})
  }
}

var obj1 = { cars: 'ford', fruit: 'peach', other: ['bar'] }
var obj2 = { cars: 'ferrari', info: 'foo', other: ['baz'] }
const result = mergeObject(obj1, obj2)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version :)

```js
var obj1 = {cars: 'ford', fruit: 'peach', other: ['bar']}
var obj2 = {cars: 'ferrari', info: 'foo', other: ['baz']}

var merge = (acc, [k, v]) => {
  if (k in acc) {
    acc[k] = [acc[k]].flat().concat(v)
  } else {
    acc[k] = v;
  }

  return acc;
}

var res = Object.entries(obj1).reduce(merge, obj2);
```